# Add Captcha to subscribe.phml

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, captcha

Hi  I tried to add captcha to subscribe.phtml
Here is my xml file.

```
    <default>
    <reference name="newsletter">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs">
                        <file>mage/captcha.js</file>
                    </action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId">
                    <formId>newsletter_subscribe</formId>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgWidth">
                    <width>230</width>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgHeight">
                    <width>50</width>
                </action>
            </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: if you can customize https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contacts</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
```

now  paste this code for captcha

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
```

Comment: Captcha is working only bellow events :

controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost
controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_forgotpassword
admin_user_authenticate_before
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
customer_customer_authenticated
admin_session_user_login_success

Comment: and need to enable in admin side

Answer (score 0):

in file '**\\template\newsletter\subscribe.phtml**' there is a form, you can add captcha and before submission of form you can proceed after validation.