# Getting many Fake Customers and Newsletter Subscribers

Tags: magento-1, customer-account, newsletter, magento1.9.3.1

I have been getting around **10 to 20 Fake customers** in my **magento 1.9.3.**

Does anyone know how to block them?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear,do you want to block these subscribed customers or want to prevent new subscribers like these

Comment: I want to block them from creating these fake profiles. They look like computer generated.

Answer (score 1):

There are  few things are need for this.

### 1. Add form key in newsletter form

First,you need to add form_key in newsletter form for preventing against Cross Site Request  and validated at form_key at   post controller .[Form Key Value in template and controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119942/form-key-value-in-template-and-controller)

### 2. Add Captcha to newsletter

Add captcha to newsletter form [Add Captcha to subscribe.phml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70351/add-captcha-to-subscribe-phml)

Comment: I am getting fake subscriber even I have these 2, the issue is the domain of email is valid but the email address itself is fake. Like: test3433434@yahoo.com etc, getting lots of emails that no email sent to the user.